# Kinematics of shooting a projectile at a target

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity

I want to determine the initial velocity given an angle at which a projectile must be launched in order to hit a target located at a distance $D$ and height $Y$ from the origin.

Following the discussion [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/431227) I have tried to solve for the velocity and came up with the following equation for the velocity:
$$v^2 = \frac{5D^2}{D \sin\theta \cos\theta - Y \cos^2\theta}$$
This was derived from $$ D = vtcos(\theta)$$
and $$Y=vtsin(\theta) - 5(t)^2$$
where I rearranged the equation for $D$ for $t$ and subsituted into the equation for $Y$.

Unfortunately, this seems to fail for values where:

$$Y = D,\theta <= 45$$

Why does my method fail for specific values of $Y$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Can you provide any contex?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Could you maybe add some context, I find it hard to answer without knowing what D,Y, $\theta$ are ans without knowing how you found this expression.

Comment: Edited, the first equation was solved for t and substituted into the second equation. @Q.Reindeerson.

Comment: @Christheyankee This still lacks some context, what is D, what is Y these type of things :). Also you are new so it is normal that you are still struggling with that but when you make an edit it is better for it to be fitted inside the question, as it had always been here. What do you mean by it fails?  For me the problem is more when $\theta <= 45$ if D = Y and they are both positive for instance. To understand why it fails it might be useful to know which physcal system it describes :)

Comment: @Q.Reindeerson it is projectile motion of a ball at a distance D from something a height Y up.

Comment: @Q.Reindeerson that situation is also an issue, correct.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/431227/

Comment: @Chair I messed up some of the algebra in that post so it became a fix my algebra and not fix my concept line of thought.

Comment: But what are you actually trying to determine? The velocity at some distance from the origin?

Comment: @nluigi the velocity a ball should be shot at if it is to hit its target some distance D, away, and Y high.

Comment: Ok, great, I have edited your question to reflect your actual question better... take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your method fails for $\theta\leq 45$, not $\theta\gt45$.

Mathematically, this is because for your situation the denominator reduces to $tan\theta-1$, which becomes negative for $\theta\leq 45$. This is a problem when subsequently taking the square root.

Physically, consider what happens for your specific values of $Y=D$; the target is located at distance of $\sqrt{2}D$ at exactly an angle of $\theta=45$ from the origin. If you now shoot your projectile at the exact same angle (or less) you will never reach the target because the tiniest bit of gravity will reduce the $y$-velocity such that it will curve under the target.